# C++ gcc/icpc disable printout of namespace in compiler messages

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Is there a flag (or another way) to provide to the C++ compiler, so that in its error messages it does not print the namespace? I would especially like this feature for gcc and icpc.

Background: I work in an evironment with deeply nested namespace with long names and it's hard to read the compiler error mesages.

In the following example I would like the compiler to not print `A::B::`:

```
error: no instance of constructor "A::B::V::V" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (A::B::M, A::B::W, A::B::X, A::B::Y)
     return V(*this, i, v[i], X());
            ^
```